# How to Fix '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am using python 3.6. I am trying to collect data and update the flow table. But current_data_flow[1] and current_data_flow[2] have ip addresses which are string. I am getting error as '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'.
I tried string type casting but it says 'must be str, not int'

Below is my code and the error.

```
class RawFlowProcessor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
    def run(self):
        while True:
            global raw_flow_data
            try:
                if not q_rawData.empty():
                    start_time = time.time()
                    current_flow_data = q_rawData.get()
                    current_flow_data = str(current_flow_data)
                    count = 0
                    for items in reversed(raw_flow_data):
                        if current_flow_data[0:5]==items[0:5]:
                        count = 1
                        #If Flow bytes and/or packets are being updated
                        if (current_flow_data[6]!=items[6] or current_flow_data[7]!=items[7]):
                            current_flow_data[8]=items[8] #Retain timestamp for the first time the flow was seen
                            if (current_flow_data[5]>FLOW_TIMEOUT): #If a Flow remains in Flow Table for more than FLOW_TIMEOUT
                                q_finalData.put(current_flow_data)
                            items[5:8] = current_flow_data[5:8] #Get the new values
                            #~ raw_flow_data.insert(idx, current_flow_data)
                            #~ raw_flow_data.remove(items)
                            #count = 1
                            break
                        #If Flow bytes and/or packets are not being updated and Flow is idle in the Flow Table
                        elif (current_flow_data[6]==items[6] or current_flow_data[7]==items[7]):
                            if (current_flow_data[5]!=0 or current_flow_data[6]!=0):
                                #count = 1
                                temp_value = items[5] + 3
                                if (current_flow_data[5]>temp_value): #To account for system delays
                                    q_finalData.put(items)
                                    break
                            elif (current_flow_data[5]==0 or current_flow_data[6]==0): #Flow not yet updated
                                #count = 1
                                break
                   if count==0: #New Flow Entry
                       raw_flow_data.append(current_flow_data)
                       raw_flow_data = sorted(raw_flow_data, key=itemgetter(8)) #Sort raw_flow_data according to last_seen
                   end_time = time.time() - start_time
                   thread_two.append(end_time)

           except Exception as ex:
           template = "An exception of type {0} occured. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
           message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
           print(message)
           print('\nRaw Flow Processor shows an error!!')
           break
```

This is the error message and I can't seem to figure out.

```
An exception of type TypeError occured. Arguments: (“'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'”,)
```

After trying string type casting error message is

```
An exception of type TypeError occured. Arguments:
('must be str, not int',)

Raw Flow Processor shows an error!!
```

Comment: convert the string number to integer?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: current_flow_data[1] and current_flow_data[2] have ip addresses, I am unable to convert string to integer.

Comment: You said that you tried string casting, but I still can't figure out which line of code the error occurs on. Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: What is `itemgetter(8)`? Also, it would be helpful if you remove the blanket `try`/`except` as it hides the line number the error is occurring on.

Comment: Please understand that the full trace back includes everything printed before the error message. That information is key and needs to be put into your question. All you are putting is the error message.

Comment: @quamrana It seems to me that the OP's `except` clause suppresses the traceback. I suspect OP might not know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very illustrative though "can't compare int and str with >". Okay! So we need to look at our comparison and think about our logic. You said in a comment that they're IP addresses so... how are you comparing them?

Is "10.10.10.10" > 42? I dunno... doesn't really make sense, does it? In reality greater than / less than never really makes sense for IP addresses. So you really have to figure out exactly what you're trying to do. For some minor tips, instead of storing your data as indices on a list, break them apart into separate variables with descriptive names, and then pull out your logic into helpfully named methods.

```
if (current_flow_data[5]>FLOW_TIMEOUT):
  q_finalData.put(current_flow_data)
```

or

```
def check_timeout(flow_data):
  return flow_data.timeout > FLOW_TIMEOUT

if check_timeout(current_flow_data):
  q_finalData.put(current_flow_data)
```

Accessing `timeout` will be easier to follow than accessing `[6]`, and reading the name of the method will be easier to follow than having all the logic inline (for something so short it may not help that much)